# new char [] in dynamic constructor throws "corrupted top size";

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a strange, at least for me, issue with dynamic allocation of char array in constructor.

I have couple of constructors and functions in my class which perform dynamic allocation of char array and only one of them throws "corrupted top size" exception from malloc();
Code is provided below and i have left the comment where exception is thrown.
The pointers are simply defined in class definition as "char *_name".
All other constructors and functions are checked and are working properly.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include "contact.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

MT::Contact::Contact() :
    _name_length(0),
    _surname_length(0),
    _birth_date_length(0),
    _phone_number_length(0),
    _city_length(0),
    _position_length(0),
    _size(0),
    _name(nullptr),
    _surname(nullptr),
    _birth_date(nullptr),
    _phone_number(nullptr),
    _city(nullptr),
    _position(nullptr),
    _to_file(nullptr),
    _new_contact(true),
    _modified_contact(false)
{

}

MT::Contact::Contact(int8_t *data) :
    _to_file(nullptr)
{
    int start = 0;
    _name_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _surname_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _birth_date_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _phone_number_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _city_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _position_length = *(data+start);
    ++start;
    _name = new char[_name_length];//Here is the exception (and for all other allocations in this constructor)
    strncpy(_name, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _name_length);
    start += _name_length;
    _surname = new char[_surname_length];
    strncpy(_surname, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _surname_length);
    start += _surname_length;
    _birth_date = new char[_birth_date_length];
    strncpy(_birth_date, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _birth_date_length);
    start += _birth_date_length;
    _phone_number = new char[_phone_number_length];
    strncpy(_phone_number, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _phone_number_length);
    start += _phone_number_length;
    _city = new char[_city_length];
    strncpy(_city, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _city_length);
    start += _city_length;
    _position = new char[_position_length];
    strncpy(_position, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _position_length);
    _new_contact = false;
    _modified_contact = false;
}

MT::Contact::Contact(const MT::Contact &other) :
    _name_length(other._name_length),
    _surname_length(other._surname_length),
    _birth_date_length(other._birth_date_length),
    _phone_number_length(other._phone_number_length),
    _city_length(other._city_length),
    _position_length(other._position_length),
    _size(other._size),
    _to_file(nullptr),
    _new_contact(other._new_contact), _modified_contact(other._modified_contact)
{
    _name = new char[_name_length];
    strcpy(_name, other._name);
    _surname = new char[_surname_length];
    strcpy(_surname, other._surname);
    _birth_date = new char[_birth_date_length];
    strcpy(_birth_date, other._birth_date);
    _phone_number = new char[_phone_number_length];
    strcpy(_phone_number, other._phone_number);
    _city = new char[_city_length];
    strcpy(_city, other._city);
    _position = new char[_position_length];
    strcpy(_position, other._position);
}

MT::Contact::Contact(MT::Contact &&other):
    _name_length(other._name_length),
    _surname_length(other._surname_length),
    _birth_date_length(other._birth_date_length),
    _phone_number_length(other._phone_number_length),
    _city_length(other._city_length),
    _position_length(other._position_length),
    _size(other._size),
    _to_file(nullptr),
    _new_contact(other._new_contact), _modified_contact(other._modified_contact)
{
    _name = other._name;
    _surname = other._surname;
    _birth_date = other._birth_date;
    _phone_number = other._phone_number;
    _city = other._city;
    _position = other._position;
    other._size = 0;
    other._name_length = 0;
    other._birth_date_length = 0;
    other._phone_number_length = 0;
    other._surname_length = 0;
    other._city_length = 0;
    other._position_length = 0;
    other._name = nullptr;
    other._surname = nullptr;
    other._birth_date = nullptr;
    other._phone_number = nullptr;
    other._city = nullptr;
    other._position = nullptr;
    other._to_file = nullptr;
}

MT::Contact &MT::Contact::operator=(const MT::Contact &other)
{
    if (this != &other){
        if (_name != nullptr){
            delete [] _name;
        }
        if (_surname != nullptr){
            delete [] _surname;
        }
        if (_birth_date != nullptr){
            delete [] _birth_date;
        }
        if (_phone_number != nullptr){
            delete [] _phone_number;
        }
        if (_city != nullptr){
            delete [] _city;
        }
        if (_position != nullptr){
            delete [] _position;
        }
        _name_length = other._name_length;
        _surname_length = other._surname_length;
        _birth_date_length = other._birth_date_length;
        _phone_number_length = other._phone_number_length;
        _city_length = other._city_length;
        _position_length = other._position_length;
        _size = other._size;
        _name = new char[_name_length];
        strcpy(_name, other._name);
        _surname = new char[_surname_length];
        strcpy(_surname, other._surname);
        _birth_date = new char[_birth_date_length];
        strcpy(_birth_date, other._birth_date);
        _phone_number = new char[_phone_number_length];
        strcpy(_phone_number, other._phone_number);
        _city = new char[_city_length];
        strcpy(_city, other._city);
        _position = new char[_position_length];
        strcpy(_position, other._position);
        _new_contact = other._new_contact;
        _modified_contact = other._modified_contact;
    }
    return *this;
}

MT::Contact &MT::Contact::operator=(MT::Contact &&other)
{
    if (this != &other){
        if (_name != nullptr){
            delete [] _name;
        }
        if (_surname != nullptr){
            delete [] _surname;
        }
        if (_birth_date != nullptr){
            delete [] _birth_date;
        }
        if (_phone_number != nullptr){
            delete [] _phone_number;
        }
        if (_city != nullptr){
            delete [] _city;
        }
        if (_position != nullptr){
            delete [] _position;
        }
        _name_length = other._name_length;
        _surname_length = other._surname_length;
        _birth_date_length = other._birth_date_length;
        _phone_number_length = other._phone_number_length;
        _city_length = other._city_length;
        _position_length = other._position_length;
        _size = other._size;
        _name = other._name;
        _surname = other._surname;
        _birth_date = other._birth_date;
        _phone_number = other._phone_number;
        _city = other._city;
        _position = other._position;
        _new_contact = other._new_contact;
        _modified_contact = other._modified_contact;
        other._size = 0;
        other._name_length = 0;
        other._surname_length = 0;
        other._city_length = 0;
        other._position_length = 0;
        other._name = nullptr;
        other._surname = nullptr;
        other._birth_date = nullptr;
        other._phone_number = nullptr;
        other._city = nullptr;
        other._position = nullptr;
        other._to_file = nullptr;
        std::cout << "Move" << std::endl;
    }

    return *this;
}

void MT::Contact::set_name(const char *name)
{
    if (name == nullptr || strcmp(name, "") == 0){
        throw std::invalid_argument("void MT::Contact::set_name(const char *name): empty [name] was provided");
    }
    _name_length = strlen(name);
    if (!_new_contact){
        delete [] _name;
        _modified_contact = true;
    }
    _name = new char[_name_length];
    strcpy(_name, name);
    _size += _name_length;
}

void MT::Contact::set_surname(const char *surname)
{
    if (surname != nullptr && strcmp(surname, "") != 0){
        _surname_length = strlen(surname);
        if (!_new_contact){
            delete [] _surname;
            _modified_contact = true;
        }
        _surname = new char[_surname_length];
        strcpy(_surname, surname);
        _size += _surname_length;
    }
}

void MT::Contact::set_birthdate(const char *birth_date)
{
    if (birth_date != nullptr && strcmp(birth_date, "") != 0){
        _birth_date_length = strlen(birth_date);
        if (!_new_contact){
            delete [] _birth_date;
            _modified_contact = true;
        }
        _birth_date = new char[_birth_date_length];
        strcpy(_birth_date, birth_date);
        _size += _birth_date_length;
    }
}

void MT::Contact::set_phone_number(const char *phone_number)
{
    if (phone_number != nullptr && strcmp(phone_number, "") != 0){
        _phone_number_length = strlen(phone_number);
        if (!_new_contact){
            delete [] _phone_number;
            _modified_contact = true;
        }
        _phone_number = new char[_phone_number_length];
        strcpy(_phone_number, phone_number);
        _size += _phone_number_length;
    }
}

void MT::Contact::set_city(const char *city)
{
    if (city != nullptr && strcmp(city, "")  != 0){
        _city_length = strlen(city);
        if (!_new_contact){
            delete [] _city;
            _modified_contact = true;
        }
        _city = new char[_city_length];
        strcpy(_city, city);
        _size += _city_length;
    }
}

void MT::Contact::set_position(const char *position)
{
    if (position != nullptr && strcmp(position, "") != 0){
        _position_length = strlen(position);
        if (!_new_contact){
            delete [] _position;
            _modified_contact = true;
        }
        _position = new char[_position_length];
        strcpy(_position, position);
        _size += _position_length;
    }
}

int MT::Contact::size() const
{
    return _size;
}

const char *MT::Contact::name() const
{
    return _name;
}

const char *MT::Contact::surname() const
{
    if (_surname == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    return _surname;
}

const char *MT::Contact::birth_date() const
{
    if (_birth_date == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    return _birth_date;
}

const char *MT::Contact::phone_number() const
{
    if (_phone_number == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    return _phone_number;
}

const char *MT::Contact::city() const
{
    if (_city == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    return _city;
}

const char *MT::Contact::position() const
{
    if (_position == nullptr){
        return "";
    }
    return _position;
}

bool MT::Contact::is_new() const
{
    return _new_contact;
}

bool MT::Contact::is_modified() const
{
    return _modified_contact;
}

int8_t *MT::Contact::to_file()
{
    if (_to_file != nullptr){
        delete [] _to_file;
    }
    _to_file = new int8_t[_size];
    _to_file[0] = static_cast<int8_t>(_size);
    _to_file[1] = static_cast<int8_t>(_size >> 8);
    _to_file[2] = _name_length;
    _to_file[3] = _surname_length;
    _to_file[4] = _birth_date_length;
    _to_file[5] = _phone_number_length;
    _to_file[6] = _city_length;
    _to_file[7] = _position_length;
    int start = 8;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _name, _name_length);
    start += _name_length;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _surname, _surname_length);
    start += _surname_length;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _birth_date, _birth_date_length);
    start += _birth_date_length;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _phone_number, _phone_number_length);
    start += _phone_number_length;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _city, _city_length);
    start += _city_length;
    memcpy(_to_file+start, _position, _position_length);

    return _to_file;
}

MT::Contact::~Contact()
{
    if (_name != nullptr){
        delete [] _name;
    }
    if (_surname != nullptr){
        delete [] _surname;
    }
    if (_birth_date != nullptr){
        delete [] _birth_date;
    }
    if (_phone_number != nullptr){
        delete [] _phone_number;
    }
    if (_city != nullptr){
        delete [] _city;
    }
    if (_position != nullptr){
        delete [] _position;
    }
    if (_to_file != nullptr){
        delete [] _to_file;
    }
}
```

...

Comment: First question to you is -- why are you not using `std::string`?  This is basically `C` code with a few C++ syntax thrown in.  As to -- *All other constructors and functions are checked and are working properly. Any help will be appreciated.* -- I bet they can be broken easily.

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mcve], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: "Corrupted top size" means the heap is corrupted. That has almost certainly happened before this code is even called. How are you initializing "data"?

Comment: Also note that [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) have a corner case where it won't write the null-terminator. Which is good since you don't allocate space for the terminator.

Comment: If this is a homework where you can't use `std::string`, may I suggest writing your own string class, similar to `std::string` (not as extensive, but does the basics).  Then use that string class instead of `char *` in your class.  Then at least all the string handling is encapsulated in one class, instead of having it strewn all over the place as you've written.  Right now, you have multiple points for failure -- writing a class reduces this to one place for failure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the move/copy constructors and assignment operators look approximately correct to me and are copying the strings where necessary

Comment: @AlanBirtles Misread it. But I found *one* possible reason for the problem: Using `strcpy` on strings that probably aren't null-terminated.

Comment: Note that for any pointer *or array* `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` es exactly equal to `p[i]`. The latter is usually easier to read and understand (and less to write as well).

Comment: That indeed is a home task and I can't use std::string. The "data" is allocated in "to_file()" function. And as soon as I can judge - as all numeric variables are read properly the data is Ok. Also I had tried to create any other dynamically allocated array and got the same exception.

Comment: @Stu The data size was the problem.

Comment: @ToEveryOne Thanks for null-terminated comments.

Comment: Errors like that in a `malloc` or `free` are frequently due to invalid behavior that happened at some earlier point in the program, not at the current line of code.

Answer (score 1):

First lets take a look at your constructor

```
MT::Contact::Contact(int8_t *data)
```

Especially all lines like these:

```
_name_length = *(data+start);
...
_name = new char[_name_length];
strncpy(_name, reinterpret_cast<char *>(data+start), _name_length);
```

Here you don't allocate space for a null-terminator. Which is good since it's very likely that the `strncpy` call won't actually add a null-terminator. This will lead to problems in your copy-assignment operator and the copy-constructor where you use

```
strcpy(_name, other._name);
```

which assumes that `other._name` *is* a null-terminated string. If it's not then `strcpy` will go out of bounds and you will have *undefined behavior*.

---

You also have a problem with how you calculate the length of the strings, because if the length are longer than 127 then that will be seen as negative, leading to problems with the allocation.

Use `uint8_t` for unsigned values instead. And of course the `_name_length` member needs to be unsigned as well (preferably a `size_t`).

Comment: I suppose not to allow to input names and surnames longer then 127 characters and will control that on input. Had searched in web and considered that 127 character is enough to store name, surname, and other fields/

Answer (score 0):

Just because you aren't allowed to use `std::string` doesn't mean you can't write your own. This compresses all the memory management (and main source of bugs) into a single place, makes your code safer, shorter and easier to understand.

I've only implemented a small part of your code but hopefully its enough to get the idea. Not tested but should probably work:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

namespace MT
{
  class String
  {
  public:
    String()
      : _data( nullptr ),
      _size( 0 )
    {
    }

    String( const String& other )
      : String()
    {
      assign( other._data, other._size );
    }

    String( String&& other )
      : _data( other._data ),
      _size( other._size )
    {
      other._data = nullptr;
      other._size = 0;
    }

    String& operator = ( const String& other )
    {
      assign( other._data, other._size );
      return *this;
    }

    String& operator = ( String&& other )
    {
      std::swap( _data, other._data );
      std::swap( _size, other._size );
      return *this;
    }

    ~String()
    {
      clear();
    }

    void assign( const char* ch, size_t length )
    {
      clear();
      _data = new char[ length ];
      strncpy( _data, ch, length );
    }

    void assign( const char* ch )
    {
      assign( ch, strlen( ch ) );
    }

    void clear()
    {
      delete _data;
      _data = nullptr;
      _size = 0;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
      return _size;
    }

    const char* c_str() const
    {
      return _data;
    }

  private:
    char* _data;
    size_t _size;
  };
  class Contact
  {
  public:
    Contact();
    Contact( int8_t* data );

    void set_name( const char* name );
    const char* name() const;

  private:
    String _name;
    String _surname;
    String _birth_date;
    String _phone_number;
    String _city;
    String _position;
    String _to_file;
    bool _new_contact;
    bool _modified_contact;
  };
}

MT::Contact::Contact() :
  _new_contact( true ),
  _modified_contact( false )
{

}

MT::Contact::Contact( int8_t* data )
{
  int start = 0;
  size_t name_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  size_t surname_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  size_t birth_date_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  size_t phone_number_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  size_t city_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  size_t position_length = *( data + start );
  ++start;
  _name.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, name_length );
  start += name_length;
  _surname.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, surname_length );
  start += surname_length;
  _birth_date.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, birth_date_length );
  start += birth_date_length;
  _phone_number.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, phone_number_length );
  start += phone_number_length;
  _city.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, city_length );
  _position.assign( reinterpret_cast<char*>( data ) + start, position_length );
  _new_contact = false;
  _modified_contact = false;
}

void MT::Contact::set_name( const char* name )
{
  if ( name == nullptr || strcmp( name, "" ) == 0 )
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument( "void MT::Contact::set_name(const char *name): empty [name] was provided" );
  }
  _name.assign( name );
}

const char* MT::Contact::name() const
{
  return _name.c_str();
}
```

Note that Contact no longer requires any move/copy constructors, assignment operators or destructor, the default implementations now do the right thing.

Fixing the bug in your code (strings aren't null terminated) can now be done in a single place rather than in lots of places by fixing the `String::assign` implementation:

```
    void assign( const char* ch, size_t length )
    {
      clear();
      _data = new char[ length + 1 ];
      strncpy( _data, ch, length );
      _data[ length ] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code and time but unfortunately the tasks says that: "All string variables should be made as C strings". Why I do not know.

Comment: I hate people who insist on trying to teach you c++ by preventing you from using c++, they might as well just teach you c

Comment: strictly all the string variables are c strings, just wrapped in a class like any sane modern c++ programmer would do